# A list of "language_LOCALE" as well as accepted languages by country?

Tags: json, localization, internationalization, locale, http-accept-language

I'm looking for a list of countries with their main language(s) as well as `Accept-Languages` ones.

For instance:

```
{
  "south africa": {
    country_code: za,
    lang: en_ZA,
    accept_languages: [en_ZA, zu_ZA, af_ZA]
  },
  "....."
}
```

Is there any list like this which I could copy?

Or from what source could I compile it?

Answer (score 2):

`accept_languages` comes from the browser, and in some browsers I am allowed to input a custom locale, whatever I want. So I can put any syntactically valid locale. For example `ja-Cyrl-ZA` (Japanese in South Africa written in Cyrillic script).

Some other browsers only give you a limited list to choose from. Some don't even allow you to specify a region, only a language. Some give you a very short list of countries.

So there are differences between browsers.

If what you really want is a list of languages used in a country, independent of `Accept-Languages`, this might be a good source of info in a machine readable format:
https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml

See the `<territoryInfo>` section.
For example the info about South Africa is a [line 4365](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml#L4365):

```
<territory type="ZA" gdp="767200000000" literacyPercent="93" population="56463600"> <!--South Africa-->
    <languagePopulation type="en" literacyPercent="99" populationPercent="31" officialStatus="official" references="R1265"/> <!--English-->
    <languagePopulation type="zu" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="24" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--Zulu-->
    <languagePopulation type="xh" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="18" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--Xhosa-->
    <languagePopulation type="af" literacyPercent="99" populationPercent="13" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--Afrikaans-->
    <languagePopulation type="nso" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="9.4" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--Northern Sotho-->
    <languagePopulation type="tn" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="8.2" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--Tswana-->
    <languagePopulation type="st" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="7.9" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--Southern Sotho-->
    <languagePopulation type="ts" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="4.4" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--Tsonga-->
    <languagePopulation type="ss" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="2.7" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--Swati-->
    <languagePopulation type="ve" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="2.3" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--Venda-->
    <languagePopulation type="hi" literacyPercent="69" populationPercent="2"/> <!--Hindi-->
    <languagePopulation type="nr" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="1.6" officialStatus="official_regional"/> <!--South Ndebele-->
    <languagePopulation type="sw" literacyPercent="50" populationPercent="0.0018"/> <!--Swahili-->
</territory>
```